# Is there any library to base64 encode/decode strings using RFC 3548 in Java

Tags: java, base64

I am trying to decode a string in java. This same string is encoded in an external system using RFC 3548. I tried different libraries such as `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` but as expected there are inconsistencies. It seems apache library is using RFC 2045. Could anyone please help me with this? This String is not static and keeps changing from invocation to invocation.

Comment: try Google's Guava libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use Google's Guava library,

`base64()`

As per its [documentation](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/BaseEncoding.html),

> The "base64" base encoding specified by RFC 4648 section 4 , Base 64
>   Encoding. (This is the same as the base 64 encoding from **RFC 3548** .)

[Download](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)

Comment: Thanks it helped!!! However after decoding the string a new line character `\n` is appended to every decoding string. Any specific reason why this happening? Example: Input 
`hello` encoded to `aGVsbG8K` decoding it back produces `hello\n`. Similar behavior is seen on all other inputs

Comment: are you sure about this behavior ? because as per its documentation "No line feeds are added by default, as per RFC 4648 section 3.1, Line Feeds in Encoded Data. Line feeds may be added using withSeparator(String, int)."

Comment: I am positive. I ended doing an ugly split on the return string

Comment: did you read this ? https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1252

Comment: and how are you displaying the decoded output ? using `println` or `print` ?

Comment: I used debug to examine the value. I was also able to confirm my endpoint rejected the value because of the line feed

Answer (score 0):

Try Apache Commons library and class

`org.apache.commons.net.util.Base64`

See: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html

Download from: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/download_codec.cgi

Answer (score 0):

There is a builtin:

```
byte[] bytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(string);
String string = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(bytes);
```

It also does hex encoding and a few other things. It was intended for encoding data into an XML document.